# Populate user details on update modal react

Tags: reactjs

I am using a one modal to create and update users on my app.This seems to be working but a few lose ends are giving me a headache.I am new to REACT so am sure there is something am missing.I have made the api calls in a separate userActions.js file and imported them here.I am setting the state as empty fields so I can use to add values.The edit button on each user opens the same modal but here am setting the state to userdetails. On the front end, I have to click on the button twice before it updates the correct details, as if it takes time before setting the state.I am not sure what is wrong with this implementation, but I will really appprecate any help

Usersetttings.js

```
function UserSettings(props) {
  const handleClose = () => {
  setModalIsOpen(false);
};
const handleChange1 = (event, newValue) => {
  setValue(newValue);
};

const [modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState(false);

const [userdetails, setUserdetails] = useState({});
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
const [userId, setUserId] = useState(0);
const [state, setState] = React.useState({
  id: '',
  username: '',
  password: '',
  email: '',
  first_name: '',
  last_name: '',
  image: '',
});
const handleChange = (e) => {
  const value = e.target.value;
  setState({
    ...state,
    [e.target.name]: value,
  });
};
const handleUserCreateUpdate = (id) => {
  setUserId(id);
  setState(userdetails);
  setModalIsOpen(true);
};

const submitHandler = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const newUser = {
    id: state.id,
    username: state.username,
    password: state.password,
    email: state.email,
    first_name: state.first_name,
    last_name: state.last_name,
    image: state.image,
  };

  const res = createUpdateUser(newUser).then((res) => {
    if (status === 201) {
    }
  });
  return res;
};

useEffect(() => {
  userListing().then((res) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    if (res.status === 200) {
      setUsers(res.data);
      setIsLoading(false);   
    }
  });
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  fetchUserDetails(userId).then((res) => {
    if (res.status === 200) {
      
      setUserdetails(res.data);
      console.log(res.data)
    }
  });
}, [userId]);

const body = (
  <div style={modalStyle} className={classes.paper}>
    <a className="text-primary">
                      <b>New User</b>
                    </a>
                    <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          class="form-control"
                          name="username"
                          placeholder="Username"
                          value={state.username}
                          onChange={handleChange}></input>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          class="form-control"
                          name="first_name"
                          placeholder="first name"
                          value={state.first_name}
                          onChange={handleChange}></input>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          class="form-control"
                          name="last_name"
                          placeholder="last name"
                          value={state.last_name}
                          onChange={handleChange}></input>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          class="form-control"
                          name="email"
                          placeholder="Email"
                          value={state.email}
                          onChange={handleChange}></input>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input
                          type="password"
                          class="form-control"
                          name="password"
                          placeholder="Password"
                          value={state.password}
                          onChange={handleChange}
                          required
                          validate={[
                            required({
                              message: 'Password is required.',
                            }),
                          ]}
                          ></input>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="form-control" placeholder="Permisions">
                          <option>Admin</option>
                          <option>Staff</option>
                          <option>User</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input
                          type="file"
                          class="form-control-file"
                          name="image"
                          placeholder="Image"
                          value={state.image}
                          onChange={handleChange}></input>
                      </div>

                      <button
                        type="submit"
                        class="btn btn-primary"
                        onClick={() => window.location.reload(false)}>
                        {' '}
                        SUBMIT{' '}
                      </button>
                      <Button onClick={handleClose} color="secondary" size="large">
                        Cancel
                      </Button>
                    </form>
  </div>
); 
return (
  <>
    <div>
    <Modal
      open={modalIsOpen}
      onClose={handleClose}
      disableBackdropClick
      aria-labelledby="simple-modal-title"
      aria-describedby="simple-modal-description">
      {body}
    </Modal>
    <div>
      <Table>
         {users.length > 0 ? (
                          users.map((user, index) => {
                            return (
                      <TableBody>
                    
                              <TableRow>
                                <TableCell data-label="Name">
                                  <FormControlLabel
                                    color="primary"
                                    control={<Checkbox name="checkedC" />}
                                  />
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell data-label="Date">
                                  {user.id}
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell data-label="Referance">
                                  {user.username}
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell
                                  data-label="Amount"
                                  className="amount">
                                  {user.email}
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell data-label="Status">
                                  <span className="pending">
                                    {user.is_active ? 'ACTIVE' : 'PENDING'}
                                  </span>
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell
                                  data-label="Action"
                                  className="d-flex align-items-center">
                                  <IconButton
                                    aria-label="close"
                                    size="small"
                                    color="primary"
                                    href="javascript:void(0);"
                                    onClick={() =>
                                      handleUserCreateUpdate(user.id)
                                    }>
                                    <Icon.Edit3 />
                                  </IconButton>
                                </TableCell>
                              </TableRow>
                           
                      </TableBody>
                        );
                      })
                    ) : (
                      <TableSkeleton />
                    )}
                    </Table>
     
    <div/>
```

Comment: seems like you ain't using hooks inside a function component. Are you?

Comment: Could you please elaborate

Comment: see the rules of using hooks in React - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html